# Display an external HTML file in a JPanel

Tags: java, html, swing, webserver

I'm writing an application launcher and I've currently got a HTML file which displays the changes to the application, this works like a charm, and everytime a new update is released I'll list the changes in the HTML file and it will automatically update in the users .exe/.jar file.

However the current method I'm using requires the user to download the .exe/.jar file for the updates to show, so how could I come across fetching the HTML file from my Webserver, and displaying it accordingly.

Here is my current code;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Launcher extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6224390548062243879L;

public static void createFrame() {

    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setEditable(false);

    java.net.URL helpURL = Launcher.class.getResource("/changelog.html");

    if (helpURL != null) {
        try {
            editorPane.setPage(helpURL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad URL: " + helpURL);
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: changelog.html");
    }

    JScrollPane editorScrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);

    editorScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    editorScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 300));
    editorScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));

    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");

    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

    JButton launch = new JButton("Launch!");

    launch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 50));

    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    f.setTitle("Stonelore Launcher");
    f.setSize(350, 400);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.getContentPane().add(editorScrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    f.getContentPane().add(launch, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createFrame();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you do is change the following line:

```
java.net.URL helpURL = Launcher.class.getResource("/changelog.html");
```

to the following:

```
java.net.URL helpURL = new URL("http://www.server.com/changelog.html");
```

Of course, you have to substitute the actual URL in the URL construtor.

Comment: While this is the solution, I would add that you should consider running `try {
            editorPane.setPage(helpURL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Attempted to read a bad URL: " + helpURL);
        }` in a new thread. Network operations on the UI thread are a bad idea.

Comment: I added in the try catch, beforehand!